# Pointwise limit

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Find the pointwise limit of the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ defined by $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 
      0, & 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} \\
     nx + \frac{2-n}{2}, & \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n} < x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
     1, & \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1.
   \end{cases}
$$
I am stuck on how to find the pointwise limit of this sequence of functions. Obviously, when $x = 0$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and so $(f_n(x)) = (0) \rightarrow 0$. Also, when $x \in \left(\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]$, $f_n(x) = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and so $(f_n(x)) = (1) \rightarrow 1$. I am getting stuck on how to find the pointwise limit when $x \in \left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. Maybe I should try to use the Archimedean property? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Note that for any $x <{1 \over 2}$ that there is some $N$ such that $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n \ge N$. A similar situation applies for $x > {1 \over 2}$. Note that $f_n({1 \over 2}) = 1$ for all $n$. Hence the limit is $1_{[{1 \over 2},1]}$.

Comment: Just sketch a few $f_n$ and you will see what is happening.

Comment: Ok, thanks! After sketching some $f_n$ it is pretty clear what is happening and what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x \in \left(0, \frac12\right)$. It is easy to see that we can find $N$ large enough such that $f_N(x)=0$. Notice as well that for $n>N$, $f_n(x) = 0$.

Hence, for $x \in \left(0, \frac12\right)$, $f_n(x) \to 0$.

It only remains to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n \left( \frac12 \right)$. I will leave this to you.